# doxygen python raise exception

Tags: python, doxygen

I'm new to using Doxygen to document my Python code.  I like to document what exceptions my methods/functions raise.  I've done this in the past using @raise, but Doxygen doesn't seem to recognize this.  I have now also tried @exception (the javadoc/Doxygen idiom), but this too does not seem to be parsed by Doxygen (the @exception or @raise line is passed through to the resulting HTML as if it were in a code/encode block).

Is there any way to convince Doxygen (I'm using 1.8.3) to parse @exception tags for Python code?

Thanks,

Brian

Comment: Just making sure, are you using `##` blocks to write your Doxygen-bound comments, or are you using `"""` blocks? The Doxygen Manual (http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/docblocks.html#pythonblocks) suggests that this makes a difference.

Comment: @AndrewSzeto link is bad.

Comment: I am using """.  It seems like Doxygen sometimes does parse \exception tags; if there is no \return tag, the \exception tags are parsed.  If there is a \return tag, the \exception tags, whether occurring before or after the \return tag, are not parsed.  I can see nothing in the documentation that indicates why this would happen. (I've substituted at signs for '\' in the above description as stackoverflow treats at signs as a mention of a previous user)

Comment: @IamChuckB bad as in outdated/incorrect information, or bad as in broken hyperlink? For what it's worth, the link is not broken for me.

Comment: @AndrewSzeto That is bizarre. DNS lookup was failing for me on the 30th and again just now. Was failing on both my work computer and my phone. Failed multiple times just now in Windows/Chrome and Ubuntu/Chromium until one time it just worked. Link address is fine after all. Something to do with the nameservers, I guess...?

Answer (score 0):

Trying with Doxygen 1.8.8 I'm getting a nice Doxygen output using the `@exception` tag. However Doxygen dictates the you specify which exception is thrown before the actual documentation.

```
 ##
 # @brief This is my function
 #
 # @exceptions MyException My function can throw a MyException
 #
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Typo: it should be `@exception` not `@exceptions`